# Docker: File (bootstrap.sh) not found in docker image while running container. Although file is present in image

Tags: image, docker, containers, devops

I have created an image to run docker container with chrome. Below is my code. My dockerfile does compile into image. But whenever I try to run container from image I get error "Bootstrap.sh file not found" Although file is present in my FileSystem snapshot inside image. You can check screenshot.

Please help me resolve this issue I am new to docker.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get clean && apt-get install -y \
    x11vnc \
    xvfb \
    fluxbox \
    wmctrl \
    wget \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list \
    && apt-get update && apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable

RUN useradd apps \
    && mkdir -p /home/apps \
    && chown -v -R apps:apps /home/apps

COPY bootstrap.sh /

CMD '/bootstrap.sh'
```

BootStrap.sh file code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Based on: http://www.richud.com/wiki/Ubuntu_Fluxbox_GUI_with_x11vnc_and_Xvfb

main() {
    log_i "Starting xvfb virtual display..."
    launch_xvfb
    log_i "Starting window manager..."
    launch_window_manager
    log_i "Starting VNC server..."
    run_vnc_server
}

launch_xvfb() {
    local xvfbLockFilePath="/tmp/.X1-lock"
    if [ -f "${xvfbLockFilePath}" ]
    then
        log_i "Removing xvfb lock file '${xvfbLockFilePath}'..."
        if ! rm -v "${xvfbLockFilePath}"
        then
            log_e "Failed to remove xvfb lock file"
            exit 1
        fi
    fi

    # Set defaults if the user did not specify envs.
    export DISPLAY=${XVFB_DISPLAY:-:1}
    local screen=${XVFB_SCREEN:-0}
    local resolution=${XVFB_RESOLUTION:-1280x960x24}
    local timeout=${XVFB_TIMEOUT:-5}

    # Start and wait for either Xvfb to be fully up or we hit the timeout.
    Xvfb ${DISPLAY} -screen ${screen} ${resolution} &
    local loopCount=0
    until xdpyinfo -display ${DISPLAY} > /dev/null 2>&1
    do
        loopCount=$((loopCount+1))
        sleep 1
        if [ ${loopCount} -gt ${timeout} ]
        then
            log_e "xvfb failed to start"
            exit 1
        fi
    done
}

launch_window_manager() {
    local timeout=${XVFB_TIMEOUT:-5}

    # Start and wait for either fluxbox to be fully up or we hit the timeout.
    fluxbox &
    local loopCount=0
    until wmctrl -m > /dev/null 2>&1
    do
        loopCount=$((loopCount+1))
        sleep 1
        if [ ${loopCount} -gt ${timeout} ]
        then
            log_e "fluxbox failed to start"
            exit 1
        fi
    done
}

run_vnc_server() {
    local passwordArgument='-nopw'

    if [ -n "${VNC_SERVER_PASSWORD}" ]
    then
        local passwordFilePath="${HOME}/.x11vnc.pass"
        if ! x11vnc -storepasswd "${VNC_SERVER_PASSWORD}" "${passwordFilePath}"
        then
            log_e "Failed to store x11vnc password"
            exit 1
        fi
        passwordArgument=-"-rfbauth ${passwordFilePath}"
        log_i "The VNC server will ask for a password"
    else
        log_w "The VNC server will NOT ask for a password"
    fi

    x11vnc -display ${DISPLAY} -forever ${passwordArgument} &
    wait $!
}

log_i() {
    log "[INFO] ${@}"
}

log_w() {
    log "[WARN] ${@}"
}

log_e() {
    log "[ERROR] ${@}"
}

log() {
    echo "[$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')] ${@}"
}

control_c() {
    echo ""
    exit
}

trap control_c SIGINT SIGTERM SIGHUP

main

exit
```

[image]
Snapshot of Error:
[image]
Proof bootstrap.sh file is present inside my docker image

Comment: `docker run -it your_image "/bootstrap.sh"`

Comment: I tried but got this error "docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"bootstrap.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown."

Comment: `docker build --no-cache -t your_image .` and seems like window interpret the path worng , try `docker run -it your_image "\bootstrap.sh"`

Comment: ` \"bootstrap.sh\":` it should be like ` \bootstrap.sh":

Comment: or try to run command in gitbash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is give the file the correct permissions. In your Dockerfile if you can add the line `RUN chmod +x /bootstrap.sh` right before you run CMD.

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

COPY bootstrap.sh /

RUN apt-get update && apt-get clean && apt-get install -y \
    x11vnc \
    xvfb \
    fluxbox \
    wmctrl \
    wget \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list \
    && apt-get update && apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable

RUN useradd apps \
    && mkdir -p /home/apps \
    && chown -v -R apps:apps /home/apps


RUN chmod +x /bootstrap.sh

CMD '/bootstrap.sh'
```

Comment: Try the Dockerfile I provided, it definitely works for me. Just ran it myself.

Comment: Output:
```
daudnadeem:mock_the_proc daudn$ docker run bootstrap
[2019-09-20 10:28:26] [INFO] Starting xvfb virtual display...
[2019-09-20 10:28:26] [INFO] Starting window manager...
Failed to read: session.ignoreBorder
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.forcePseudoTransparency
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.colorsPerChannel
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.doubleClickInterval
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.tabPadding
Setting default value
Failed to read: session.styleOverlay
Setting default value
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem solved. After adding "RUN chmod +x /bootstrap.sh" I needed to set linux line endings for bootstrap.sh file by replacing \r\n with \n in notepadd++ with extended search mode in order to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:
CMD sh /bootstrap.sh

DockerFile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

COPY bootstrap.sh /

RUN apt-get update && apt-get clean && apt-get install -y \
    x11vnc \
    xvfb \
    fluxbox \
    wmctrl \
    wget \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list \
    && apt-get update && apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable

RUN useradd apps \
    && mkdir -p /home/apps \
    && chown -v -R apps:apps /home/apps


CMD sh /bootstrap.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was changing `#!/bin/bash` for `#!/bin/sh`

I think it would depend on the image you are using. If it uses `bash` or `sh` for running a script with `CMD`.

Info about the difference: [Difference between sh and Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)